Magento 2 : Punchout Store - Purchase Button Click GTM Tracking Not Working
I have setup button click Purchase event with data-layer in Magento 2 Punchout store. But when I click the button "Transfer Cart to Ariba" (Purchase button) event is not triggering in GTM. It is taking me in Purchaser dashboard. I don't know what actually the problem.

<script type="text/javascript">
    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
        "transaction_id": "12345",
        "value": 10.1,
        "currency": "USD",
        "tax": 3.6,
        "shipping": 5.99,
        "items": {
            "item_id": "SKU_12345",
            "name": "Stan and Friends Tee",
            "item_list_name": "Related Products",
            "category": "Testing",
            "quantity": "5",
            "price": "10"
        }
    });
</script>

Here is the code.

Share the code which you try?

Update the code into the question it self by editing the question.
